# Acer Asphire 5930G automatic shutdown

Tags: overheating, laptop-repair

I have this Acer Asphire 5930G laptop. It is almost 3 years now. But currently it Boots up or Go to Windows but it automatically shutdown within more or less than 5-10 minutes.

I already checked the HDD and memory and it is ok. I already clean the cpu fan and I notice that the heat sink is too hot.

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: *> I already clean the cpu fan and i notice that the heat sink is too hot.*   That could be it. Check the temperatures (e.g., with [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php)) to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Acer Aspire 5930G` is literally a very hot machine. Many people are having heating issues on this laptop.

I don't know if you are ready to spend a few bucks on your laptop if required, but this is just my version of what you should be doing to solve the problem:

- Upgrade you [BIOS](http://support.acer-euro.com/drivers/notebook/as_5930.html) to v1.23 from the Acer support website. Hopefully, it may give you control over the fan speeds and other features.
- There are also [unlocked / modded versions](http://www.bios-mods.com/forum/Thread-ACER-ASPIRE-5930G) of the BIOS which give you full control. But try it at your own risk, and definitely backup your old BIOS before you try the modded ones.
- Also monitor the CPU and GPU temperatures using [HWMonitor](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/hwmonitor.html). If they are high or too high, then your hardware might be wearing out! And since you have cleaned out the dust and the vents etc. nothing except for an extra cooling solution is going to help!
- Most people have complained that the heating issues are caused because of the MXM slot graphics card on the laptop, the NVIDIA GeForce 9600M GT. And this is the cause of the hangs and restarts and shut downs.
- A couple of guys replaced it with an ATI Radeon 3650 HD card, and had controlled the heating.
- Others suggest the only way to keep it going is to get a Laptop Cooler.

Some links you should refer to:

- [Overheating Issues](http://fixitwizkid.com/threads/overheating-issues.338/)
- [Acer Aspire 5920G Overheating Problems](http://forum.notebookreview.com/acer/500131-acer-aspire-5920g-overheating-problem.html)
- [Temperature Monitoring Guide](http://forum.notebookreview.com/notebook-dummy-guide-articles/81852-monitoring-notebook-temps-nvidia-ati-cpu-hdd-do-your-temps-worry-you.html)
- Attaching an image of the default / standard / expected temperatures for the Acer Aspire 5930G

[image: Default Temperature]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
I released the back plate, and removed the fan (top right).
The fan output was filled with dust and dirt.
I cleaned the fan and reinstalled it.
Now everything seems to be working.